# How to handle exceptions thrown in streams map without try catch?

Tags: java, exception, java-stream

I want to handle the exception without using try catch clauses.

```
void test() {
    list.stream().map(obj -> {
        Batch batch = x.findByBatchId(obj.getBatchId())
            /// exception is thrown here
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("")); 

        if (obj.getBatchStatus() != null) {
            batchHelper.updateBatchStatus(batch, obj.getBatchStatus());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are explicitly throwing the exception. How about _not_ throwing it, and just returning the empty optional instead?

Comment: @AndyTurner i need it to throw the exception explicitly when it can't find the batchId in the repository

Comment: @tthog you say you want to _handle_ the exception without try/catch. You don't need to throw an exception, catch an exception, then do something: just do the thing. (Plus, of course, you need a terminal operation on the stream, or it will never evaluate).

Answer (score 2):

You can't throw checked exception that way.

You can:

1. Throw RuntimeException and handle it later, maybe in another method, or don't handle it at all:

   ```
    public void test() {
    list.stream().map(obj -> {
        Batch batch = x.findByBatchId(obj.getBatchId())
                /// exception is thrown here
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(""));

        if (obj.getBatchStatus() != null) {
            batchHelper.updateBatchStatus(batch, obj.getBatchStatus());
        }
    });
   ```
2. Use **for statement** and add your exception to method signature:

   ```
    public void test() throws  ResourceNotFoundException {
    for (BatchInfo bi: list) {
        .findByBatchId(bi.getBatchId()).orElseThrow(
                () -> new ResourceNotFoundException(""));
    }
   ```

It also depends on what you want to do in case of exception.
If you just want to let users know they do something wrong - use RuntimeException

3. If you want just update Batch status, use **forEach**, not **map** :

   ```
    list.stream().forEach(obj -> {
        Batch batch = x.findByBatchId(obj.getBatchId())
                /// exception is thrown here
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(""));

        if (obj.getBatchStatus() != null) {
            batchHelper.updateBatchStatus(batch, obj.getBatchStatus());
        }
    });
   ```

Comment: "Use for statement" there is no reason no to use `orElseThrow` here, as in the original code and the other two cases.

Comment: @AndyTurner you're right.

Comment: @AndyTurner But in the original code there can't be thrown any checked exception without try catch. I mean, you can't throw it from inside `map` method of stream, as written in the original code. You can throw only `RuntimeException`, which is not always appropriate